# File is possibly corrupt - Checksum error when installing Win7

Tags: windows-7, checksum

I've just built a new dev server. I am putting Windows 7 on it as I don't have a Server license and just picked up an OEM W7 Pro license.

I am getting the message:
*The file is possibly corrupt. The file header checksum does not match the computed checksum.*

Has anyone seen this before? Specs are nothing special, but all brand new today - SATA hard drive, IDE DVD reader (this was recycled), 4GB Kingston RAM.

Any ideas on how to get it to boot the DVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anyone seen this before?

Yes. Broken hardware. Possibly a bad drive or install medium - wherevery ou get the data from. ALso memory errors or soemthing like that is possible.

> Any ideas on how to get it to boot the
>   DVD?

Replace it. Broken, scratched, DVD reader issue. Anything like it.

> I've just built a new dev server. I am
>   putting Windows 7 on it as I don't
>   have a Server license and just picked
>   up an OEM W7 Pro license.

Use an MSDN license. THe last hing I would ever touch is any OEM license.

Comment: Thanks mate. Turns out the DVD drive was kaput. I just dumped the disc onto a USB stick and ran the boot tool and working a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Dev server and windows 7- this sounds like a bad idea already. As TomTom mentions, get an MSDN licence and you can run whatever server licence you want for minimal cost- as long as its exlusivly for development work.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the works...